# how about using OWASP dependency check tool to address Top 10 2013-A9-Using Components with Known Vulnerabilities

Tags: owasp

I know the [OWASP dependency check tool](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check) is really good in finding vulnerable dependencies and I have used it personally for experimental purposes. But, has anybody used it at an enterprise level, like scanning for vulnerable jars in an established product?

Comment: The primary author uses it extensive at the company he works for, which is a *very* large enterprise.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have seen this tool as one of the dependencies before going to production in an enterprise level organisation.

I have to say that it's not flawless and requires quite the attention due to false positives. These false positives can be placed in an ignore file.

However, I think it's a nice "extra" to have before releasing a product to production.

Comment: Good to know it has been used at enterprise level i was more concerned on authenticity of the product than false positives.